# How to initialize a @Binding Array

Tags: swiftui

So I'm doing some refactoring and I ran across this line of code that I wanted to refactor:

```
struct MyView: View {
     @State private var myArrayOfCustomObjects = [CustomObject]
     let text: String
          var body: some View {
             Text(text)
          }
}
```

Then when I wanted to refactor the view as so..

```
struct ExtractedView: View {
  @Binding var customObjects: [CustomObject]
  let text: String

  init(customObjects: Binding<Array<CustomObject>>, text: String) {
    self.customObjects = customObjects  // Error: 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

        // Also tried _customObjects = customObjects
    self.text = text

  }
     var body: some View {
          
        Text(text)
     }
}
```

This code is simplified of course but I fear I may be getting that error due to some complexity I'm not exposing in the example. Any feedback is welcome

What am I doing wrong??

( I also have an `Environment` instance (managedObjectContext) and a coreData class - which has some logic inside of the init that are being initialized too but didn't think it was relevant for this code example )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work! also try clean your build folder and build your project first.

```
struct ExtractedView: View {
  @Binding var customObjects: [CustomObject]
  let text: String

  init(customObjects: Binding<Array<CustomObject>>, text: String) {
    self._customObjects = customObjects

    self.text = text

  }
     var body: some View {
          
        Text(text)
     }
}


struct CustomObject { }
```